# How to put second section underneath button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Have a section of my website where when the button is pressed the button moves to the left and the text that is originally collapsed then shown moves the button and is side by side the button, what I am trying to do is so that when the button is clicked the text appears underneath with some padding on the top of the text, might be simple but as a beginner I have checked documentation and google searched but have been unsuccessful, thank you in advanced!

Code:

```js
const sourcesButton = document.querySelector('#bibliographySources');
let bibliographySources = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");

bibliographySources.style.display = "none";

function showSources() {
  let sourceStyling = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");
  if (sourceStyling.style.display === "none") {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.sourcesButton {
  position: relative;
}

.footerStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sourceStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.bibliographySources {
  padding: 1 0 0 0rem;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #655A06;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="footerStyling" id="footer">
    <a onclick="showSources()" id="#bibliography" class="btn rounded btn-outline-light sourcesButton">Sources</a>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="row sourceStyling bibliographySources" id="bibliographySources">
      <p>
        Carbon Neutral by 2040 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>World goal of Carbon Neutrality by 2050 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>Donut Chart showing the sources of emissions amongst industries (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskpower looking to supply power through solar energy & more by 2030 (Praill, 2018)<br>
        <br>Canada GHG Emission Heatmap - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan’s CO2 Emissions 76.4Mt in 2018 - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Canada’s CO2 Emissions 728Mt in 2018 - (Government of Canada, 2019)<br>
        <br>Sources of GHG Emissions from Federal Fleets in Canada - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>221 MW of operating wind capacity spread across 143 turbines, generating 3.1% of Saskatchewan's electricity - (SaskWind, 2020)<br>
        <br>
      </p>
      <h3>
        References
      </h3>
      <p>
        <br>Government of Canada. (2019). Government of Canada. Retrieved from Greenhouse gas emissions:<br> https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/environmental-indicators/greenhouse-gas-emissions.html<br>
        <br>Oleksyn, M. (2021, April 27). SES report sees carbon neutral grid by 2040 possible for SaskPower. Retrieved from Prince Albert Daily Herald:<br> https://paherald.sk.ca/2021/04/27/ses-report-sees-carbon-neutral-grid-by-2040-possible-for-saskpower/<br>
        <br>Praill, C. (2018, June 19). SaskPower announces 10 megawatt solar project, first in Sask. Retrieved from Global News:<br> https://globalnews.ca/news/4284462/saskpower-announces-10-megawatt-solar-project-first-in-sask/<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan. (2020). Retrieved from Greenhouse Gas Emissions:<br> https://www.saskatchewan.ca/residents/environment-public-health-and-safety/state-of-the-environment/saskatchewans-state-of-the-environment/greenhouse-gas-emissions<br>
        <br>SaskWind. (2020). SaskWind. Retrieved from Location of Saskatchewan Wind Farms:<br> https://www.saskwind.ca/location-of-sk-wind-farms<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: there are a few quality answers here. If any of them helped solve your question, please mark that as the answer. If not, please respond with further clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were missing `flex-direction: column` on your flex container:

```js
const sourcesButton = document.querySelector('#bibliographySources');
let bibliographySources = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");

bibliographySources.style.display = "none";

function showSources() {
  let sourceStyling = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");
  if (sourceStyling.style.display === "none") {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.sourcesButton {
  position: relative;
}

.footerStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sourceStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.bibliographySources {
  padding: 1 0 0 0rem;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #655A06;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="footerStyling" id="footer">
    <a onclick="showSources()" id="#bibliography" class="btn rounded btn-outline-light sourcesButton">Sources</a>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="sourceStyling bibliographySources" id="bibliographySources">
      <p>
        Carbon Neutral by 2040 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>World goal of Carbon Neutrality by 2050 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>Donut Chart showing the sources of emissions amongst industries (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskpower looking to supply power through solar energy & more by 2030 (Praill, 2018)<br>
        <br>Canada GHG Emission Heatmap - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan’s CO2 Emissions 76.4Mt in 2018 - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Canada’s CO2 Emissions 728Mt in 2018 - (Government of Canada, 2019)<br>
        <br>Sources of GHG Emissions from Federal Fleets in Canada - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>221 MW of operating wind capacity spread across 143 turbines, generating 3.1% of Saskatchewan's electricity - (SaskWind, 2020)<br>
        <br>
      </p>
      <h3>
        References
      </h3>
      <p>
        <br>Government of Canada. (2019). Government of Canada. Retrieved from Greenhouse gas emissions:<br> https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/environmental-indicators/greenhouse-gas-emissions.html<br>
        <br>Oleksyn, M. (2021, April 27). SES report sees carbon neutral grid by 2040 possible for SaskPower. Retrieved from Prince Albert Daily Herald:<br> https://paherald.sk.ca/2021/04/27/ses-report-sees-carbon-neutral-grid-by-2040-possible-for-saskpower/<br>
        <br>Praill, C. (2018, June 19). SaskPower announces 10 megawatt solar project, first in Sask. Retrieved from Global News:<br> https://globalnews.ca/news/4284462/saskpower-announces-10-megawatt-solar-project-first-in-sask/<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan. (2020). Retrieved from Greenhouse Gas Emissions:<br> https://www.saskatchewan.ca/residents/environment-public-health-and-safety/state-of-the-environment/saskatchewans-state-of-the-environment/greenhouse-gas-emissions<br>
        <br>SaskWind. (2020). SaskWind. Retrieved from Location of Saskatchewan Wind Farms:<br> https://www.saskwind.ca/location-of-sk-wind-farms<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `flex-direction: column;` to your ***footer*** and `align-items: center;` to center as column.

From MDN on changing the main axis: `If we change our flex-direction to column, align-items and align-self will align the items to the left and right.`

```js
const sourcesButton = document.querySelector('#bibliographySources');
let bibliographySources = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");

bibliographySources.style.display = "none";

function showSources() {
  let sourceStyling = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");
  if (sourceStyling.style.display === "none") {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.sourcesButton {
  position: relative;
}

.footerStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.sourceStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.bibliographySources {
  padding: 1 0 0 0rem;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #655A06;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="footerStyling" id="footer">
    <a onclick="showSources()" id="#bibliography" class="btn rounded btn-outline-light sourcesButton">Sources</a>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="row sourceStyling bibliographySources" id="bibliographySources">
      <p>
        Carbon Neutral by 2040 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>World goal of Carbon Neutrality by 2050 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>Donut Chart showing the sources of emissions amongst industries (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskpower looking to supply power through solar energy & more by 2030 (Praill, 2018)<br>
        <br>Canada GHG Emission Heatmap - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan’s CO2 Emissions 76.4Mt in 2018 - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Canada’s CO2 Emissions 728Mt in 2018 - (Government of Canada, 2019)<br>
        <br>Sources of GHG Emissions from Federal Fleets in Canada - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>221 MW of operating wind capacity spread across 143 turbines, generating 3.1% of Saskatchewan's electricity - (SaskWind, 2020)<br>
        <br>
      </p>
      <h3>
        References
      </h3>
      <p>
        <br>Government of Canada. (2019). Government of Canada. Retrieved from Greenhouse gas emissions:<br> https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/environmental-indicators/greenhouse-gas-emissions.html<br>
        <br>Oleksyn, M. (2021, April 27). SES report sees carbon neutral grid by 2040 possible for SaskPower. Retrieved from Prince Albert Daily Herald:<br> https://paherald.sk.ca/2021/04/27/ses-report-sees-carbon-neutral-grid-by-2040-possible-for-saskpower/<br>
        <br>Praill, C. (2018, June 19). SaskPower announces 10 megawatt solar project, first in Sask. Retrieved from Global News:<br> https://globalnews.ca/news/4284462/saskpower-announces-10-megawatt-solar-project-first-in-sask/<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan. (2020). Retrieved from Greenhouse Gas Emissions:<br> https://www.saskatchewan.ca/residents/environment-public-health-and-safety/state-of-the-environment/saskatchewans-state-of-the-environment/greenhouse-gas-emissions<br>
        <br>SaskWind. (2020). SaskWind. Retrieved from Location of Saskatchewan Wind Farms:<br> https://www.saskwind.ca/location-of-sk-wind-farms<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option. Use flex on the footer div that holds the button and let the rest be normal layout. Just edit `footer` and move it's `flex` rules into `#footer`

```
footer {
  background-color: #655A06;
}
#footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```js
const sourcesButton = document.querySelector('#bibliographySources');
let bibliographySources = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");

bibliographySources.style.display = "none";

function showSources() {
  let sourceStyling = document.getElementById("bibliographySources");
  if (sourceStyling.style.display === "none") {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    sourceStyling.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.sourcesButton {
  position: relative;
}

.footerStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;

}

.sourceStyling {
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
   width:100%;
}

.bibliographySources {
  padding: 1 0 0 0rem;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  background-color: #655A06;
}
#footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="footerStyling" id="footer">
    <a onclick="showSources()" id="#bibliography" class="btn rounded btn-outline-light sourcesButton">Sources</a>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="row sourceStyling bibliographySources" id="bibliographySources">
      <p>
        Carbon Neutral by 2040 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>World goal of Carbon Neutrality by 2050 (Oleksyn, 2021)<br>
        <br>Donut Chart showing the sources of emissions amongst industries (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskpower looking to supply power through solar energy & more by 2030 (Praill, 2018)<br>
        <br>Canada GHG Emission Heatmap - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan’s CO2 Emissions 76.4Mt in 2018 - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>Canada’s CO2 Emissions 728Mt in 2018 - (Government of Canada, 2019)<br>
        <br>Sources of GHG Emissions from Federal Fleets in Canada - (Saskatchewan, 2020)<br>
        <br>221 MW of operating wind capacity spread across 143 turbines, generating 3.1% of Saskatchewan's electricity - (SaskWind, 2020)<br>
        <br>
      </p>
      <h3>
        References
      </h3>
      <p>
        <br>Government of Canada. (2019). Government of Canada. Retrieved from Greenhouse gas emissions:<br> https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/environmental-indicators/greenhouse-gas-emissions.html<br>
        <br>Oleksyn, M. (2021, April 27). SES report sees carbon neutral grid by 2040 possible for SaskPower. Retrieved from Prince Albert Daily Herald:<br> https://paherald.sk.ca/2021/04/27/ses-report-sees-carbon-neutral-grid-by-2040-possible-for-saskpower/<br>
        <br>Praill, C. (2018, June 19). SaskPower announces 10 megawatt solar project, first in Sask. Retrieved from Global News:<br> https://globalnews.ca/news/4284462/saskpower-announces-10-megawatt-solar-project-first-in-sask/<br>
        <br>Saskatchewan. (2020). Retrieved from Greenhouse Gas Emissions:<br> https://www.saskatchewan.ca/residents/environment-public-health-and-safety/state-of-the-environment/saskatchewans-state-of-the-environment/greenhouse-gas-emissions<br>
        <br>SaskWind. (2020). SaskWind. Retrieved from Location of Saskatchewan Wind Farms:<br> https://www.saskwind.ca/location-of-sk-wind-farms<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
```